# Tensorflow bounded regression vs classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, regression

As part of my masters thesis I have been tasked with predicting a label integer (0-255) which is a binned representation of an angle. The feature columns are also integers, in the range (0-255).

So far I have used the custom Tensorflow layers estimator, implementing a 256 output classifier which performs well. However, my issue with the classification approach I am using is the following:

- My classification model thinks that predicting a 3 instead of a 28 is as good/bad as predicting a 27 as a 28

The numerical interval / ordinal nature of my data (not sure which) leads me to believe that if I used regression I would achieve results with less drastically incorrect predictions or outliers.

**My goal**: 
to reduce the number of drastically incorrect predicted outliers

**My questions**:

1. Is regression the better approach, or can I improve my
   classification to include an ordinal/interval relationship between
   my labels?
2. If I choose regression, is there a way to bound my predicted output between 0-255 (I know I will have to round float values predicted).

Thanks in advance. Any other comments, suggestions or ideas to help me to best tackle the problem are also very helpful.

If I made any incorrect assumptions or mistake in my interpretation of the problem feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Regression is the simpler approach, however, you can also use classification and manipulate the loss function to have a lower loss for misclassifications that are "close" to the original class.

Question 2: The tensorflow command for bounding your prediction is `tf.clip_by_value`. Are you mapping all 360 degrees to `[0,255]`? In that case you will want to consider the boundary cases, i.e. your estimator yields -4 and the true value is 251, but they are the actually representing the same value so loss should be 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am mapping [-180 180] to [0 255], so this would require consideration of boundary cases as you suggest. I am thinking that this is an ordinal regression (classification all but in name) problem, where I will have to use an embedding such as [0 0 0...] = 0, [1 0 0 ...] = 1, [1 1 0.....]=2 etc. This will introduce a "larger than" relationship in my output classes. However, considering the boundary conditions, this embedding may need tuning, although I am not sure yet how.

Comment: You can simply flip values at the boundary: `x = x - tf.nn.relu(x - 255)`. That might be simpler than ordinal regression.